# How to create process flow formula base

Tags: javascript, flowchart

I would like to create flow chart with dynamic formulas

### a = 12 b = 3% c = 4

Let’s say

> (a+b)*c

is one equation it can be

> (a-b)/c

so how to make flow chart dynamical based on formula.

Comment: https://mathjs.org/

Comment: is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart) what you mean by flow chart? Note: you've used a tag that "shouldn't be used"

Comment: Yes flow chart I wanted to make